# How to handle partial/full page submit

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, razor

I have an edit page with 2 submit buttons. Now I have a third that would encapsulate both edit sections. The formCollection on the controller has "Edit1" fields only. How do I pass all the data?  (If I remove both using statements for Edit1 and Edit2, I get all data).

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("EditAll", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EditAll" }))
{ 
    <div>
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Edit1", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Edit1" }))
    {   
        ... 
        <button name="Submit" style="float: right;" class="client">Edit 1</button>
    }

    @using(Html.BeginForm("Edit2", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Edit2" }))
    {   
        ... 
        <button name="Submit" style="float: right;" class="client">Edit 2</button>
    }
    </div>
    <button name="Submit" style="float: right;" class="client">Edit All</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this article about having multiple submit buttons: http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/

Basically you will use this code:

```
public class HttpParamActionAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute {
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo) {
        if (actionName.Equals(methodInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        if (!actionName.Equals("Action", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return false;

        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        return request[methodInfo.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

In coordination with giving your submit buttons' 'name' attribute the name of the action method to call.

Comment: You might want to include something from that article in your answer as a quote, as links sometimes become broken, which would most likely get this answer flagged for removal.

Comment: Good idea I will add some from the article.